# Transistor Collector current rating

Tags: transistors

I wish to use a transistor for switching. 
The datasheet says it allows a maximum collector current (continuous) of 200mA.
If my application just requires pulses of current every 1 second, would the transistor be able to pass through an Amp?

Is there a way, I can calculate or figure out the maximum collector current, when its not continuously flowing through it?

Comment: Please provide a link of the transistor you are trying to use. Also why can't just select another transistor with  higher current specs?

Comment: Sounds like a 2N3904 or 2N3906.

Comment: The maximum current rating of a transistor is often based on the capability of the connecting leads inside the transistor case. Too much current will melt the leads due to heating.   Thus the maximum pulsed current will usually be higher than the continuous rated current but only if the pulse width and repetition rate create less heat than the continuous rated current.  This is dependent on the transistor construction and thus the transistor data sheet should be consulted.

Comment: To find the maximum pulse current, keep giving it increasing pulses until it breaks.  The value of the one pulse before the last is then your answer.  This does not, of course, guarantee what the next device out of the bin can do.  To be sure, test each one.

Answer (score 4):

How to find the pulse current rating? **LOOK IN THE DATASHEET**, of course.

I don't understand what is so ambiguous about "maximum".  If the datasheet says the maximum current is 200 mA, then that is all you can put thru the device and expect it to adhere to the other specs.  Some datasheets may provide a additional maximum pulse current spec.  If so then there is your answer.  If not, the "maximum" current spec is still your answer.  There is nothing ambiguous here.

If you are asking what you can get away with despite what the datasheet says, then you've come to the wrong place.  We do engineering here, which wishful thinking and religious beliefs have nothing to do with.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way, I can calculate or figure out the maximum collector current, when its not continuously flowing through it?

If the maximum current is exceeded, losses in the device create excessive heat in the device, leading to its destruction.

If you are operating the device at a lower duty cycle, the first thing you will want to check is that your average power is below the same power that would exist if the device were operated under maximum continuous current conditions. If you exceed this, something will melt, no way around it.

If your average power is less, you still may not be in the clear. Often, datasheets will also include a maximum pulsed current, and specify the length of that pulse. If your pulses are both shorter and of less magnitude than this specification, you are in good shape.

Some datasheets also have something in the graphs section that give a derating curve based on duty cycle and pulse width. Use that, if you have it.

If not, you are down to intuition or guessing. Here's the problem: whenever you exceed the continuous current, you are leading the device towards destruction. If you do it too much or too long or without enough time to recover between pulses, that's bad. It's like touching something too hot with your finger: you might be able to handle it on for half a second, then off for half a second. You can't handle it on for 10 seconds, and off for 10 seconds, even though the average heat is the same in either case.

My advice: 1A is not very much current. If you can't find specific information in the datasheet to know that you won't damage the device, look for a more robust device. A transistor rated even for 1A continuous will not set you back more than a few cents.

Comment: I might add that even if it's rated for 1A continuous it may not be reliable switching 1A if it's an inductive load or if the switching is not fast. You have to stay within (_well_ within I would say) the Safe Operating Area (SOA) region. Personally, I would look for something more like a 3A device unless the load is really benign.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your transistor package is TO-92  with Rθjc=83 °C/W and Rθja=200°C/W, and can dissipates 0,625W at a Icmax about 200mA DC.
Under this conditions the case is 52°C hotter than the junction, but the case is running 73°C hotter than the surrounding air (25°C).
The junction temperature Tj will be 25+73+52=150°C which is the maximum operating temperature.
So even with 200mA DC, your transistor requires a kind of heatsink if transistor operates contnuously in Icmax. For such small packages, heatsinks of around 60°C/W are available (or you can do by yourself) helps to keep the junction temperature bellow 150°C, and in this case at around 125°C.

In order to calculate power dissipation in pulse operation environment the thermal time constant should be considered

[image]

and the “Transient  Thermal Response” data required . Usually this information are not available in such small transistors. In any case don’t expect to reduce more than half the θjc even if your 1A pulse lasts 100ms (duty cycle=0,1). BUT you are asking to increase the power around 5 times, so even with the above heatsink, the junction temperature will rise at around 220°C after some pulses.

[image]

Some critical temperatures: at 200°C some solders melting 
and 280°C is the typical melting point of die attach solder.

Answer (score 0):

If the continuous absolute maximum rating states 200mA AND there is no indication (like on graphs) of what the pulsed current rating is (usually associated with some statement of duty cycle) then you should assume that the continuous rating is like a quick-acting fuse rating and not go above it.

On what I've said above, you can't recalculate a peak current based on some small duty cycle AND if the transistor were capable of running on more current why would the manufacturer hold-back on this info? They want to sell the part and if it fits a few more percent of applications then it's money in their pocket.

However, if it's a one-off project or design then go for it BUT calculate what's the worst that could happen if the transistor went short circuit or open circuit - You don't want to damage expensive speakers (crap example but I think you know what I mean) - it might be that a fault on the transistor takes out the next transistor and so on and so forth leading to a fire (worst case example). Do a risk analysis and take the risk if you don't have any other BJTs.